# Drush add aliases for ubuntu drush?

Tags: filesystem, package-management

I natively installed ubuntu with the package manager through `apt-get install drush` .

After a `find` i discovered that they're natively installed at `/usr/share/drush`.

My question is the following: is it possible to add aliases with the ubuntu brewed drush? If so where? in the `/usr/share/drush/` folder?

The ubuntu version seems to be missing the example folder as well as some other files: ini, topic files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instructions on creating aliases, see `drush topic docs-aliases`, which can also be found at http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-4.x:/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php

The best place to put global aliases would be in /etc/drush; user-specific aliases should go in $HOME/.drush.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder in your drush folder called 'aliases'. In that folder you can create a file aliases.drushrc.php (or project specific -> myproject.aliases.drushrc.php) and i guess it should work then. so first try /usr/share/drush/aliases/aliases.drushrc.php, and see if that works.

If you put the drush location in your path, you can place the alias file in a drush folder in your home directory

there's more linux specific info in the readme.txt
http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-4.x:/README.txt